# Latex: Make title bold

Tags: latex, pdflatex, xelatex

Currently I draw my title like this.

```
{\fontsize{20}{19}\selectfont%
Title bla bla bla\par
}
```

However, I don't know how to make the title bold. Putting the title text inside a \textbf bracket does not work.

Comment: Please make a [mre] that shows us which documentclass and other settings you use